# How to query Eloquent relational tables based on json ids

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have a `articles` table with a field named `article_categories`.
I have a `categories` table with `id` field.

In my `Article Model` I have defined:

```
public function category(){
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class,'id','article_categories');
}
```

the categories in the `articles` table are saved as json like `["1","3","24"]`

in my `ArticleController` I want to retrieve all `categories` of a specific `article`.
In my `edit function` in the `ArticleController` I have this function:

```
public function edit(Article $article)
{
    $category_ids = implode(',',json_decode($article->article_categories)) ; //this gives me 1,3,24

    /////////
   // HERE SHOULD COME THE QUERY WHICH I DON'T KNOW
   // $article_categories = ?????????? 
    ////////
    
    $categories = Category::all();

    return view('article.edit', compact('articles','categories','article_categories'));
}
```

From what I've researched, there is no way to do this with Laravel but I don't know if this is true or not. I'm using Laravel 8.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should know that you violated a `many-to-many` relation in a single column and that's not valid. What you should do is a pivot table `article_category` or `category_article` and in both `Article` and `Category` models you will define a `many-to-many` relation

like so

```
class Article extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
    }
}
```

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Article::class);
    }
}
```

And in your controller you can do

```
public function edit(Article $article)
{
    $categories = Category::all();

    return view('article.edit', compact('article','categories'));
}
```

And in the view you will have direct access to `$article->categories`

---

In your current situation you can do this

```
public function edit(Article $article)
{
    $category_ids = json_decode($article->article_categories)

    $article_categories = Category::whereIn('id', $category_ids);

    $categories = Category::all();

    return view('article.edit', compact('article','categories','article_categories'));
}
```